# LDAP search can't find user inside company if not specifying region

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

I am developing an application that will be used inside our company potentially worldwide. The LDAP search for getting user details works as long as I specify the region, as in:

```
using (DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=EMEA,DC=company,DC=com")))
{
    Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
    Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
    Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
    
    Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" + UserName + "))";
    SearchResult Result = Searcher.FindOne();
}
```

As you can see, currently I am specifying the EMEA region when searching inside the company name, and this way it correctly returns my user. But I wanted to remove the EMEA region condition, as likely users from within the company, but outside the EMEA region, will also need to access the application.

I am not really familiar with the LDAP structure so I am not sure how that should be done?

The UserName variable comes from `string LogonIdentity = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\\')[1];`, where the Name originally containts "EMEA\\USERNAME" but I remove the "EMEA\\" part. How could I use this to find the user in LDAP worldwide?

Comment: What does worldwide mean? The same username in a different domain (different then EMEA for example) is a different user.

Comment: I mean that I work for Company, and Company has many plants worldwide. At Company, I work for a plant in the EMEA region. But other users might connect to the app that also work for Company, but from a plant in a different region (South America, for example). So I need an LDAP search that can find all Company users worldwide, not just in the EMEA region.

Comment: I suspect that the regions are referrals at the top level.  I'm thinking that you need to follow referrals.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the LDAP structure, what does this mean?